# Docker Bind Mount Read Initial Container Data

Tags: image, docker, tomcat, mount

**Describing The Problem**

I have created a docker tomcat image

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install openjdk-14-jre-headless -y
RUN apt-get install tomcat9 -y
ENV CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat9"
ENV CATALINA_BASE="/var/lib/tomcat9"
CMD $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run
```

This creates an image where the directory `/var/lib/tomcat9` contains the following directories
`conf  lib  logs  webapps  work`
Those directories are already populated.

On the host machine, I have the directory `/some/path/tomcat9` which is empty.

How can I run a container of this image (using which bind mount settings) so that the host directory `/some/path/tomcat9` will reflect the initial state of the container directory `/var/lib/tomcat9` and changes made to the host directory `/some/path/tomcat9` are also made to the container directory `/var/lib/tomcat9`.

**Attempts**

- If i were to use named volumes, I will have to perform any changes as root
- If i were to use default bind mount settings, the container directory `/var/lib/tomcat9` will have all of its content removed to match the host directory `/some/path/tomcat9`

**Other Questions**

- If there is no bind mount setting that solves this problem. Can you suggest any workarounds that don't include rebuilding a new image on every small change in my web application?
- What is the standard setup for developing tomcat applications on docker?

Comment: Almost every SO Java question I've seen `COPY`s a built `.jar` or `.war` file into the image; so do day-to-day development outside of Java, and rebuild your image (including the application jar) when you have a change you specifically need to run in the Docker environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to use docker environment for development. Rebuilding image on every small change doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: You have to rebuild the jar file on every small change anyways; rebuilding the image should be pretty quick (again, especially if it's just `COPY` the jar file into the Tomcat image).